# Insert in a list random of 0 and 1 with a certain number of 1's

Tags: python, random

How do I generate a list of length *N* with random 0 and 1 values , but with a given number of 1's put randomly in the list.

For example, I want a list of 10 elements(0 and 1) and the numbers of 1's in the list to be 7.

How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Dang, good point. I usually don't answer with no attempt, but this one was a "I didn't know that was already in the standard library" issue, which still happens to me. I'm okay with pointing someone towards where it is already available.

Comment: Here is what I did first time , but then I realised that I need a certain number of 1's and that's why I didn't post the code, I forgot about this, sorry.   x = [sample ([0,1],1)[0] for k in range(self.size)]

Comment: @GritcoAndreea, kindly have a look at my answer in case you wanna experiment with numpy :)

Answer (score 3):

You can make the list have the right number of 0's and 1's pretty easily

```
data = [0] * 3 + [1] * 7
```

and then use random.shuffle to make their positions within the list random

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(data)
print data
```

> [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

Comment: instead of just code dumping for a homework question, why not explain your answer?

Answer (score 1):

An approach not using `random.shuffle`:

```
import random
random.sample([0]*3 + [1]*7, 10) # [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)

```
import numpy as np
from random import shuffle
A = np.ones(7, dtype=np.int)          // [1 1 1 1 1 1 1] and data-type as integer
B = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.int)         // [0 0 0] and data-type as integer
C = np.concatenate((A, B), axis = 0)  // [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
shuffle(C)                            // [1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1]
print C
```

Comment: Why use `numpy`, but then you use `random`, when you might as well use `numpy.random.shuffle` which is optimized for `np.array`s... but even more importantly, why *numpy at all* since the OP asks for a *list*.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment :) I am trying to get hands on Python by learning through SO. What does `OP` mean btw ?

Comment: it's shorthand for "original poster", so, just the person who asked the question. The issue I'm bringing up is that `numpy` is a powerful tool for particular use-cases, but outside of that, it's rather clunky. `numpy` arrays are not replacements for vanilla python lists, and one shouldn't encourage people to think of them that way. Now, if you are using a very-large, multidimensional list and want to crunch some numbers on it or use linear algebra, *then* `numpy` would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I like the *shuffle()* approach in the other answers; however, there is another way that uses fewer calls to the random number generator.  Start with a list of zeros.  Then use *sample()* to pick the 7 indicies that should be set to ones:

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> result = [0] * 10
>>> for i in sample(range(10), k=7):
        result[i] = 1

>>> result
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```